# How to fetch a photo from Photos Library into Unity Game on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, photo-gallery

I have a Unity application for iOS and I need to fetch an image from the iPhones photos library and then use it within unity as a texture/2D sprite. I can not find any information on how it could be done.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Create a Unity Plugin in Objective-C++.. Call SendMessage to tell unity to read the pixels for the image and its width and height. Create a texture from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, I think that you are going to need a native plugin. You can either write it yourself (maybe the harder way) or try to find one from the asset store. I don't remember if this is the case anymore, but you may need to have paid for Unity to use / create plugins however.

If you want to try the native plugin route, which is actually a lot of fun in my experience, here is the start of the documentation for it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

I would suspect that you would need to make APIs that are accessible to the Unity side of code that let you call into Objective-C which in turn would call the relevant bits of code at the platform level.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1143996/open-ios-media-browser-and-import-selected-image-a.html
And scroll all the way down

I believe it answers your question of accessing an image from the photo library. Good luck!